# How to iterate over a columns of tickers of stocks and retrieve their financial data?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

My data is basically columns of stock tickers such as this:

```
MMM ABT ABBV    AC  AGRO    AUB AIR AAF BABA    AGN ... UBER    UTX VRTX    DG  V   VOW VOW3    VTBR
```

I want to use a for loop to iterate for each ticker and retrieve closing prices. Now I have this as an output:

```
for ticker in data:    
    df = DataReader(ticker,'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
```

it only outputs information about one stock ticker

i feel that i am missing something

Comment: `for ticker in data.columns:`

Answer (score 0):

If datatype is a string, try to use the split function.

```
for ticker in data.split():
    df = DataReader(ticker,'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
```

I hope this could help.

Comment: I tried using the split function. However I got an error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'